# Error in discrete_scale with unused argument when using ggplot2 and ggflags

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a strange error when using the `ggplot2` add-on package `ggflags`, one that only affects my work computer; at home I can write charts using `ggflags` with no issues.

The `ggflags` documentation is here: https://github.com/baptiste/ggflags

And this is the suggested example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggflags)

set.seed(1234)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(50), y=rnorm(50), 
            country=sample(c("ar","fr", "nz", "gb", "es", "ca"), 50, TRUE), 
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, country=country, size=x)) + 
  geom_flag() + 
  scale_country()
```

At home, this runs with no problem, reproducing the graph shown on the README on Github, however on my work machine I get the following error message:

> Error in discrete_scale("country", "identity", scales::identity_pal(),  : 
>   unused argument (super = ScaleDiscreteIdentity)

This seems to be a fairly obscure error, and I am not finding any results on Stack Overflow to explain why this (pretty basic) bit of code will work on one machine and not on the other. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling RStudio, as well as deleting and reinstalling the relevant packages from my package library, but I've had no joy in getting this package to work on my office machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you compared your `sessionInfo` between your home and work computers to look for differences in operating systems, package versions, etc?

Comment: may be related to this: https://github.com/baptiste/ggflags/pull/2/commits/9e12780c69d3ac0f012b25f0840251aa3fdd2fd1

Comment: There were different versions of ggplot2 so I tried re-installing that and various other packages via `devtools::install_github`, as [outlined here](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/10).

Now I have this new error on my work machine:

`Error: GeomFlag was built with an incompatible version of ggproto.
Please reinstall the package that provides this extension.`

Answer (score 0):

`gglflags` from the [original author](https://github.com/ellisp/ggflags) was not updated when `ggplot2` updated (development is abandoned for the original version). Please use the `ggflags` version from: https://github.com/jimjam-slam/ggflags, which I know to be functional with the recent `ggplot2` version.